# Did Rimsky-Korsaskov really quote Beethoven?

Tags: melody, beethoven

It is well-known that "Russian Five" (Balakirev, Borodin, Cui, Mussorgsky, and Rimsky-Korsakov) sought to compose purely Russian music and worked to avoid sounding "Western."  I was surprised in listening to Rimsky-Korsakov's *Scheherezade* to hear what sounded to me like an obvious quotation of the opening motive of Beethoven's fifth symphony.

Here is the passage in specific, from the beginning of the fourth movement of Scheherezade.  Between the red brackets.

[image]

And here of course is the Beethoven.

[image]

Rimsky-Korsakov's melody is a major second lower, and his E-natural would need to be an E-flat to correspond exactly.  But the rhythmic content of four accented unison notes and their development with a descending sequence is unmistakable.

If Rimsky-Korsakov was really trying to create purely Russian music, I can't imagine how he could have done this intentionally and thought it wouldn't sound Western.  But I also have a hard time believing that he never heard this symphony...

So, which is it? **Is this a quotation, or an accident, or something else?**

Comment: To me this doesn't look like a quote. Others will probably disagree. Unless someone comes up with a reference to a statement from Rimsky-Korsakov this is opinion-based.

Comment: Beethoven wrote an anacrucis. R-K did not. So, rhythmically, they're not the same, only similar. Then there's the interval... while they're both M3, Beethoven used ^5 and ^3, R-K  did not.

Comment: @Tim Beethoven cleverly disguises the fact that the motif is an anacrusis. It's not until the seventh measure that it becomes clear.

Comment: @PiedPiper - or you watch the conductor.

Comment: @Tim It's mostly conducted like a triplet.

Comment: @PiedPiper - yes, but still an anacrucis.

Comment: It seems like must be some Russian (or Levantine, considering the subject matter of Scheherezade) folk music form that resembles the passage even more closely than the excerpt of LVB's 5.

Comment: It's deceptively hard to hear the quotation as a quotation, since the Beethoven emphasizes the 2nd 8th note, while the Rimsky-Korsakov emphasizes the 1st 8th note instead.

Comment: @PiedPiper - I tend to get annoyed at conductors (and recordings) where it is conducted like a triplet, with the accent(s) at the wrong place(s).

Comment: I don't think that I have ever seen a conductor conducting Beethoven's 5th as a triplet. Conductors usually make a heavy down beat on the pause in the first bar. A very energetic gesture and then the 3 eight notes that follows are played vigorously by the strings with an up bow stroke on the first eight note thus emphasizing the anacrusis.

Comment: @Dekkadeci true, but there IS the matter of the corona rest. The rest is what leads me to think it was a simple nod. On the other hand, the corona with Beethoven is not over a rest, but over a note.